# GMAT. How do you tell if a number is divisible by a divisor using prime factors?

Tags: prime-factorization

Say I have a dividend (15) and a divisor (6). Using prime numbers, how do I tell if the dividend is divisible by the divisor?

The primes for 15 are $5^13^1$.
The primes for 6 are $3^12^1$.

What's the rule regarding prime factors and divisibility? The divisor needs to have only the prime factors of the dividend, in any amount, but no other factors?

But a number is a multiple of another number if it contains at least the factorization of the smaller number? Is that correct? For example:

45 has a factorization of $3^25^1$
15 has a factorization of $3^15^1$
9 has a factorization of $3^2$

The above 3 are factors of 45.

But:
12 has a factorization of $2^23^1$

12 is not a factor because of the extra 2 right? 45 is not a multiple of 12 because it does not contain the factorization of 12 right?

Comment: The dividend has to have all the prime factors of the dividend (and possibly others), and at least as many each prime factor.  So $60 = 2^2 3^1 5^1$ is divisible by $6=2^13^1$ and $12=2^2 3^1$ but not by $24=2^3 3^1$  or by $14 = 2^1 7^1$

Comment: You mean the dividend has to have all the prime factors of the divisor?

Comment: Yes - and you have to take into account multiplicity

Answer (score 3):

Choose whichever way you find more convenient to remember:

---

The exponent of each factor in the **dividend** must be larger than or equal to the exponent of the corresponding factor in the **divisor** (if no such factor exists in the divisor then it's OK, just keep checking).

---

The exponent of each factor in the **divisor** must be smaller than or equal to the exponent of the corresponding factor in the **dividend** (if no such factor exists in the dividend then stop checking, the answer is no).

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question. There is a lot about this property and it is used everywhere in Number Theory. The fact that every integer can be broken down as such is referred to as the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). However, we typically only consider the positive integers, since the only difference between the two is a sign change.

If we have a number, for example $360$, and we wish to know  its divisors, we first decompose it as a product of primes: 
$$360 = 2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1$$

Although it doesn't take much to show, we know that if a number $r$ divides $360$, it is of the form $2^a3^b5^c$ where $0 \leq a \leq 3$, $0 \leq b \leq 2$, and $0 \leq c \leq 1$.

And yes, a number is a multiple of another if its prime factorization is "inside" the other numbers'. For example, we know that $9$ divides $360$ since $3^2 = 9$ and $3^2$ is in the prime decomposition of $360$.

Comment: What does the "its" refer to in your second to last sentence? Does it refer to "another" or "number"?

Comment: @Jwan622 that number which is a multiple.